# Why are my synonyms returning nothing?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch, and right now I am trying to figure out why my synonyms are not returning any results like I expect them to.

I created a custom filter and analyzer for my synonyms file and applied the analyzer to both the `_all` field and explicitly defined the `specialty` field to use it as well.

When I search for `"specialty": "aids"` **without** the analyzer/tokenizer, it gives me zero results as expected.

However, when I search for `"specialty": "aids"` **with** the analyzer/tokenizer, I expect it to give me the same results as searching for `"speciality": "retrovirology"`, which should yields 3 results, but it comes back with nothing.

Is there something wrong with how I am approaching this?

---

Here are my settings and some sample data:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/personsearch"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/personsearch" -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "XYZSynAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "XYZSynFilter"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "XYZSynFilter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "aids, retrovirology"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "xyzemployee": {
      "_all": {
        "analyzer": "XYZSynAnalyzer"
      },
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "middleName": {
          "type": "string",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "specialty": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "XYZSynAnalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/personsearch/xyzemployee/1" -d'
{
  "firstName": "Don",
  "middleName": "W.",
  "lastName": "White",
  "specialty": "Adult Retrovirology"
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/personsearch/xyzemployee/2" -d'
{
  "firstName": "Terrance",
  "middleName": "G.",
  "lastName": "Gartner",
  "specialty": "Retrovirology"
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/personsearch/xyzemployee/3" -d'
{
  "firstName": "Carter",
  "middleName": "L.",
  "lastName": "Taylor",
  "specialty": "Pediatric Retrovirology"
}'

# Why is this returning nothing?
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/personsearch/xyzemployee/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "specialty": "retrovirology"
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't lowercasing anywhere.
Try this:

```
{
 "settings": {
   "index": {
     "analysis": {
       "analyzer": {
         "XYZSynAnalyzer": {
           "tokenizer": "standard",
           "filter": [
             "lowercase", "XYZSynFilter"
           ]
         }
       },
       "filter": {
         "XYZSynFilter": {
           "type": "synonym",
           "synonyms": [
             "aids, retrovirology"
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Note: you may want to split your index analyzer and search analyzer, and choose only one of them to do the synonyms. Expanding them only during indexing will speed search results.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, the filter was `"lowercase"`, not `"lower"` for those stumbling upon this quesiton

Comment: I should have checked first. Edited for the same reason. :-)